# Angular template conditions performance

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using the latest angular and recently has some doubt related to template conditions and performances. I know that calling method in template is bad practice and it is called every change detection cycle but I am not sure for the other 2 solution.

```
 1) <div *ngIf="isConditionsTrue"></div>
 2) <div *ngIf="isConditionsTrueFunction()"></div>
 3) <div *ngIf="condition1 || condition2 && !condition3"></div>
```

And in the ts file:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.isConditionsTrue = this.condition1 || this.condition2 && !this.condition3;
}

isConditionsTrueFunction(): boolean {
   return this.condition1 || this.condition2 && !this.condition3;
}
```

What is the best options in we talked about:

**a) Readability** .  I guess 1 is the winner.

**b) Performance**  I am curious between 2 and 3. Does angular has some caching mechanism like in pure pipes and does not calculate conditions in template every time, or 2 and 3 are the same ?

**c) Architecture** I know that 2 is bad practice. Does the 3 consider as bad practice since we use expression in the component template ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it`s OK to call methods in template if you use ChangeDetection.OnPush

Comment: I know that, but there are couple more questions here more specific. For me more important is difference between 1 and 3.